# Can I get a dump of the data stored in my Evernote account?

Tags: backup, evernote, export

Let say I want to leave [Evernote](http://evernote.com) but I want to get at least a rough backup of my data.

Can I get a dump of the data stored in my [Evernote](http://evernote.com) account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the only way to accomplish this is to install the (free) Evernote desktop client, select all notes and choose "Export..." from the File menu.

There are different export formats available: Evernote (.enex), Web Site (.html) and Web Archive (.mht).

Comment: good one, i was already considering writing my own via the exposed APIs.